# cannot read property 'score' of undefined

Tags: javascript

i know there are loads of other similar questions to do with this area but none of them answers have worked. in my case i have the following code and i am trying to sort an array of records in descending order by their score.

```
function score(string, pattern){
  string = string.toLowerCase();
  pattern = pattern.toLowerCase();

  var position = 0;
  var count = 0;
  while (true) {
    var index = string.indexOf(pattern, position);
    if (index == -1) break;
    count++;
    position = index + 1;
  }
  return(count);
}

function urlScores(web, pattern){
  var records = {};
  var results = [];
  var n = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < web.length; i++){
    n = score(web[i].content, pattern);
    if(n != 0){
      records.url = web[i].url;
      records.score = n;
      results[results.length] = {url: records.url, score: records.score};
    }
  }
  return(JSON.stringify(results));
}

function rankedScores(web, pattern){
  results = JSON.parse(urlScores(web, pattern));
  var temp = 0;
  var tempUrl = '';
  while(counter < results.length){
    for(var i in results){
      numbers[numbers.length] = results[i].score;
      if(results[i].score < results[i + 1].score){
        temp = results[i].score;
        tempUrl = results[i].url;
        results[i] = {url: results[i+1].url, score: results[i+1].score};
        results[i + 1] = {url: tempUrl, score: temp};
      }
    }
    counter++;
  }
  alert(JSON.stringify(results));
}
```

the very last function is what is giving me problems. if the user runs the following:

> var web = [ {url : "www.southampton.ac.uk",  content : "Southampton University offers degree               programmes and world class research test." } , {url : "www.xyz.ac.uk",  content : "An alternative     University test test test" } , {url : "www",  content : "Yet another University test" } ];
>
> rankedScores(web, 'test');

it should output the same array but in descending order. instead i get a cannot read property 'score' of undefined. can any one see where i've gone wrong?
thanks
also, we are not allowed to use .sort()!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function rankedScores(web, pattern){
  var results = JSON.parse(urlScores(web, pattern));
  var temp = 0;
  var tempUrl = '';
  var counter = 0;
  var numbers = [], i, len = results.length;

  while (counter < results.length){
    for (i = 0; i < len - 1; i++){
      numbers[numbers.length] = results[i].score; /// ???? 

      if (results[i].score < results[i + 1].score){
        temp    = results[i].score;
        tempUrl = results[i].url;

        results[i]     = {url: results[i+1].url, score: results[i + 1].score};
        results[i + 1] = {url: tempUrl, score: temp};
      }
    }

    counter++;
  }

  alert(JSON.stringify(results));
}
```

Comment: thanks! i can see how you fixed it! i removed 'numbers' as that was a previous attempt at trying to solve it and was not needed. very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

In `rankedScores`, you are using `results[i+1].score` in your `if`, but if there is no such element of `results` (because `i` is the index of the last one), you would get the error described.

Comment: i thought this could be an issue but i have traced this solution on paper and it should work up until the last one. how can i terminate at the last one so it does output the correct values without an error?

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
if(results[i].score < results[i + 1].score){
```

For the last element in the array, results[i+1] will not exist. Try adding another condition to catch that case:

```
if(typeof results[i + 1] != 'undefined' && results[i].score < results[i + 1].score){
```