# TypeError: Cannot read property 'score' of undefined

Tags: javascript, sorting, typeerror, rank

I know there are similar questions out there including [cannot read property 'score' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26787610/cannot-read-property-score-of-undefined) but they had `if(typeof results[i + 1] != 'undefined' && results[i].score < results[i + 1].score){`. Here I have a `counter-1` happening with a condition that when the counter is 0 something else happens. Honestly I just need a second pair of eyes on this. Perhaps I'll figure out the issue soon but does anyone have any input on how to make the rank go 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5?

```
var gamesArray = [
      { name: 'Edward', score: 21, rank: 0 },
      { name: 'Sharpe', score: 37, rank: 0 },
      { name: 'And', score: 45, rank: 0 },
      { name: 'The', score: 12, rank: 0 },
      { name: 'Magnetic', score: 3, rank: 0 },
      { name: 'Zeros', score: 37, rank: 0 }
    ];

    var sorted = gamesArray.sort(function(a,b){return b.score-a.score});
    // console.log (sorted);
    // [ { name: 'And', score: 45, rank: 0 },
    //   { name: 'Sharpe', score: 37, rank: 0 },
    //   { name: 'Zeros', score: 37, rank: 0 },
    //   { name: 'Edward', score: 21, rank: 0 },
    //   { name: 'The', score: 12, rank: 0 },
    //   { name: 'Magnetic', score: 3, rank: 0 } ]

    function rank(array) {

      var firstArray = array;
      var rankedArray = [];
      var counter = 0;

      while (firstArray.length > 0) { 

        //.shift removes the first slot of array and returns it
        var game = firstArray.shift();

        if (rankedArray.length == 0) {
          game.rank = 1;
          rankedArray.push(game);    
          game = null;
          counter += 1;

        } else {
          if (game.score == rankedArray[counter - 1].score) {
            game.rank = rankedArray[counter - 1].rank;
            counter += 1;
          } else {
            game.rank = rankedArray[counter - 1].rank + 1;
            counter += 1;
          };
        };

      };
      return rankedArray;
    };

    rank(gamesArray);
```

the error I get while running this is

```
   if (game.score == rankedArray[counter - 1].score) {
                                            ^
   TypeError: Cannot read property 'score' of undefined
```

Comment: when counter is `0` you will try to access `rankedArray[-1]`

Comment: are you sure @JaromandaX? ```if (rankedArray.length == 0) {
          game.rank = 1;
          rankedArray.push(game);    
          game = null;
          counter += 1; ``` this should make it so that when the rankedArray is 0, the counter is set to 1

Comment: hmmm - you have a point, I didn't follow the flow from the beginning did I :p

Comment: The easiest way to find out is to put `console.log(counter - 1);` on the previous line.

Comment: and when i do `rankedArray[1].score`  it also gives me `TypeError: Cannot read property 'score' of undefined`

Comment: I think you want to be adding "game" to your rankedArray in all cases.  Am I wrong?  You increment counter for all branches of your if/else statements, so you end up evaluating rankedArray[1] which does not exist.

Comment: Your rankedArray will only ever have one entry, therefore, once you get to the 3rd firstArray value, you will be trying to access rankedArray[1] ... which is undefined

Comment: thanks @jeffcarey I'm going to look into that, I'll be right back

Comment: This strategy destroys the original array. Consider using something like *reduce* to build a new array, or *forEach* to modify the rank without destroying the original.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you only push a game on the first iteration. I've marked the moved line in the code below.

```
var gamesArray = [
      { name: 'Edward', score: 21, rank: 0 },
      { name: 'Sharpe', score: 37, rank: 0 },
      { name: 'And', score: 45, rank: 0 },
      { name: 'The', score: 12, rank: 0 },
      { name: 'Magnetic', score: 3, rank: 0 },
      { name: 'Zeros', score: 37, rank: 0 }
    ];

    var sorted = gamesArray.sort(function(a,b){return b.score-a.score});
    // console.log (sorted);
    // [ { name: 'And', score: 45, rank: 0 },
    //   { name: 'Sharpe', score: 37, rank: 0 },
    //   { name: 'Zeros', score: 37, rank: 0 },
    //   { name: 'Edward', score: 21, rank: 0 },
    //   { name: 'The', score: 12, rank: 0 },
    //   { name: 'Magnetic', score: 3, rank: 0 } ]

    function rank(array) {

      var firstArray = array;
      var rankedArray = [];
      var counter = 0;

      while (firstArray.length > 0) { 

        //.shift removes the first slot of array and returns it
        var game = firstArray.shift();

        if (rankedArray.length == 0) {
          game.rank = 1;
          counter += 1;
        } else {
          if (game.score == rankedArray[counter - 1].score) {
            game.rank = rankedArray[counter - 1].rank;
            counter += 1;
          } else {
            game.rank = rankedArray[counter - 1].rank + 1;
            counter += 1;
          };
        };

        // Moved line
        rankedArray.push(game);
      };
      return rankedArray;
    };

    rank(gamesArray);
```

Comment: @RobG That's up the author to fix, I only copied the code and fixed the bug. But yes, that would be preferred.

Comment: @Oleander you may be right, but your code block doesn't seem to work for me when I run it

Comment: @JacobGiberson What would be your expected output? From what I can see here it works.

Comment: @Oleander, this is what I get and what I want to get `[ { name: 'And', score: 45, rank: 1 },
  { name: 'Sharpe', score: 37, rank: 2 },
  { name: 'Zeros', score: 37, rank: 2 },
  { name: 'Edward', score: 21, rank: 3 },
  { name: 'The', score: 12, rank: 4 },
  { name: 'Magnetic', score: 3, rank: 5 } ]`

Comment: @RobG thanks, I just refactored it to just one counter ++

Comment: @JacobGiberson That's exactly my output.

Comment: now it works for me, not sure what happened, thanks @Oleander

Answer (score 0):

First you shouldn't use length directly in a loop.

Second your error is from the counter being incremented even though there is nothing but the first game push in the array :)

I presume it happens of the third iteration, on the first the game is pushed on the second, it's checked on the third it's trying to find something that doesn't exist(index 1)

Comment: No, that's not the problem. Run the code your self or look at my answer.

Comment: Ah funny, yes, it turns out everything was fine, except I wasn't pushing any new games!

Comment: ```} else {

      if (game.score == rankedArray[counter - 1].score) {
        game.rank = rankedArray[counter - 1].rank;
        rankedArray.push(game);    

        counter += 1;
      } else {
        game.rank = rankedArray[counter - 1].rank + 1;
        rankedArray.push(game);    
        counter += 1;
      };
    }; ```

Comment: @JacobGiberson Why make things to complicated? Just push the `game` once. Look at my code example.

Comment: @Oleander It seems his intent is to push the games :D :D :D

Comment: You mean the guess? Erm... That's just to help him figure it out :) I am not validating anything ^^

Answer (score 0):

loop1: `And` being pushed in `rankedArray` with rank `1`, `counter` grows.

now: `firstArray.length` is 5, `rankedArray.length` is 1, `counter` is 1

loop2:
`Sharpe` being modified with rank `2`, no pushing, `counter` grows.

now: firstArray.length is 4, rankedArray.length is 1, counter is 2

loop3: trying to access `rankedArray[counter - 1].score`, which now equals `rankedArray[1].score`. However `rankedArray` holds only one element.

SO: `rankedArray[1]` is undefined, BOOM~~~